# Adding element with jquery to empty list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Hi I need to add items to list, it works when the list have elements but when list is empty **javascript return undefined**.

this is my function: namevalue is undefined when list is empty I think its main problem.

```
function submitAjaxForm(formId) 
{
   var form = $("<form></form>");
   var targetID = formId.substr(1);
   form.append($(formId).html());
   var nameValue = $(formId).find('.showDictionariesList').first().find('input[type="hidden"]').first().attr('name');  
   var indexToCut = nameValue.indexOf('[', nameValue.indexOf('[', 0) + 1);
   var featureIndex = nameValue.substring(0, indexToCut);
   var contentVal = $("#dropDownList option:selected").val(); 
   var returnValue = form.serializeArray();
   returnValue[returnValue.length - 1].value = contentVal;
}
```

This list

```
public List<ShowDictionaryModel> ShowDictionaries { get; set; }
```

class of this items:

```
public class ShowDictionaryModel
{
   public long Id { get; set; }  
   public string Value { get; set; }  
   public long? ProductId { get; set; } 
   public string FeatureId { get; set; }

   internal static ShowDictionaryModel FromDto(DictionaryDto dto)
   {
      ShowDictionaryModel model = new ShowDictionaryModel();
      model.Id = dto.Id;
      model.Value = dto.Value;
      model.ProductId = dto.ProductId;
      model.FeatureId = dto.FeatureId;
      return model;
   }
}
```

Cshtml code: showDictionariesList is class who contains the list what i want to modify

```
@model MultiShop.Panel.Models.Product.AddProductFeatureTextModel
<div>
        <div id="featureText-@Model.TypeId">

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TypeId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsRequired)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.Label(Model.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value)
            @if (Model.IsRequired)
            { 
                <span class="requiredField"></span>
            }
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Value)
            <div class="showDictionariesList">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ShowDictionaries)
            </div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDictionaryItemId, new SelectList(Model.DictionaryItems, "Id", "Value", Model.SelectedDictionaryItemId), new { id = "dropDownList" })

            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="@("submitAjaxForm('#featureText-" + @Model.TypeId + "')")" />
        </div>
        //}
```

Comment: Which list are you talking about? Would be helpful to see JavaScript error too.

Comment: I edited main post with cshtml code.

Comment: Is better if you share compiled `HTML` not the `cshtml` code

Comment: why dont you just check if `namevalue` is not `undefined` before working with `namevalue`

Comment: I can but when i do this the code still will not work when the list is empty. `namevalue`  have correct value when list have element otherwise `namevalue` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

your problem that youre trying to get attribute on non existing object
you should get it after check

```
var container = $(formId).find('.showDictionariesList').first();
var nameValueObj = container.find('input[type="hidden"]').first();
if (nameValueObj.length !== 0){
   // input was found so we can get name attribute
   var nameValue= nameValueObj.attr('name');
   var indexToCut = nameValue.indexOf('[', nameValue.indexOf('[', 0) + 1);
   // .........
} else{
   // as far no input elements inside .showDictionariesList your logic to add first one item
   // container.append(
}
```

Comment: I know but I need to get this `$(formId).find('.showDictionariesList').first().find('input[type="hidden"]').first();` when list is empty. Have You any Idea?

Comment: sorry I;m confused, if list is empty .showDictionariesList won't contain items, could you you show piece of your rendered html you want to get access to

Comment: FeatureTexts[0].ShowDictionaries[0].Id <- i need to get this

Comment: and what list is empty?

Comment: I get undefined when list is empty.

Comment: if function submitAjaxForm(formId) used as you wrote it, you can totally remove these lines    var nameValue = $(formId).find('.showDictionariesList').first().find('input[type="hidden"]').first().attr('name');  
   var indexToCut = nameValue.indexOf('[', nameValue.indexOf('[', 0) + 1);
   var featureIndex = nameValue.substring(0, indexToCut);

Comment: I really need these line of code because I use it in ajax function later :) Sorry I just don't wrote all line of code because it works for not empty list and i have problem with empty list. When i have list with items i get this FeatureTexts[0].ShowDictionaries[0].Id, when i have empty list i get undefined.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you will show here <div class="showDictionariesList"> element content you have on the page

Comment: Its normal authors list, its show only names of author added to product. But when product is new, it don't have any authors and when u want to add first author the script doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated answer,when you adding first element you trying to get first input and get name attr, but you don't have items in it yet, so first you shoul make check, if there inputs you using curent logic if no you should set forexample var featureIndex = 0 ; directly you shouldn't calculate index

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for it. I just initialize list with basic element if is null. My experience with programming is very low so my code look bad but it works as I want.

```
if (!dictionaryType.HasItems())
        {
            DictionaryDto newForEmptyList = new DictionaryDto();
            List<DictionaryDto> newList = new List<DictionaryDto>();
            newForEmptyList.FeatureId = type;
            newForEmptyList.ProductId = productId;
            newForEmptyList.Value = "";
            newForEmptyList.Id = -1;
            newList.Add(newForEmptyList);
            dictionaryType = newList.ToArray();
        }
```